# Two checkboxes, either one checked or the other, not both, how in vue.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two pricing option checkboxes in my jobs board, one is make a job sticky for one week, the other to make a job sticky for one month.  How can I implement this using Vue.js?  Obviously, one can be clicked OR the other, but not both.  Both checkboxes start as unchecked.

Comment: Use radio-button ?

Comment: For this you shouldn't use checkboxes but [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio)

Answer (score 0):

You should use radio type inputs for that case, using the same "name" attribute for both:

```html
  <input type="radio" id="week" value="week" name="jobPostingLength" v-model="jobPostingLength">
  <label for="week">1 Week</label>

  <input type="radio" id="month" value="month" name="jobPostingLength" v-model="jobPostingLength">
  <label for="month">1 Month</label>
```